# Splitting a string with regex, ignoring delimiters that occur within braces

Tags: c++, regex, qregexp

Suppose I have a string

> `Max and Bob and Merry and {Jack and Co.} and Lisa`.

I need to split it with `and` being the delimiter, *but only if it does not occur within curly braces*.

So from the above string I should get 5 strings:
`Max`, `Bob`, `Merry`, `Jack and Co.`, `Lisa`.

I tried something like this pattern:

```
[^\\\{.+]\\band\\b[^.+\\\}]
```

But it doesn't work - `Jack` and `Co.` are still split as well (I use C++ so I have to escape special characters twice).

Comment: Are lookaheads supported by the qregexp? If so, try [`\\band\\b(?![^{]*})`](https://regex101.com/r/0Fd1tF/1) might need more escaping.

Comment: In C++, you can use a *raw string literal* for regular expressions, enclosed by `R"(` and `)"`.
This way, backslashes can be used directly, i.e. `R"(\d*)"`

Comment: You want to split with too many conditions, that sounds like matching with 2 steps can prove better: 1) extract what is inside braces with `QRegExp("\\{([^{}]*)\\}")` and 2) split with `"\\{[^{}]*\\}|\\s*\\band\\b\\s*"`

Comment: bobble bubble, thanks, that seems to work exactly as expected. (Yes, lookaheads are supported in QRegExp, and QRegularExpression supports lookbehinds as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are supported by the QRegExp you can check if inside braces by looking ahead at the final word boundary if there is a closing `}` [with no opening](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `{` in between.

```
\band\b(?![^{]*})
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0Fd1tF/1)

Need to be escaped as desired or try the raw string literal like @SMeyer commented.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, partially based on the comment by [bobble-bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble). It will produce the five strings as requested, without surrounding whitespace or curly brackets.

```
std::string text = "Max and Bob and Merry and {Jack and Co.} and Lisa";
std::regex re(R"(\}? +and +(?![^{]*\})\{?)");

std::sregex_token_iterator it(text.begin(), text.end(), re, -1);
std::sregex_token_iterator end;

while (it != end)
    std::cout << *it++ << std::endl;
```

I tried to keep it simple, you might want to replace the spaces around `and` with full whitespace detection. An interactive version is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/jgwqin/1).

Answer (score 0):

Let the `{...}` part match first. That is, put it on the left side of `|`.

```
\{.*?\}|and
```

That will match `{foo and bar}` if possible, but if not then it will try to match `and`.

Comment: This will split on `{...}`, removing it.

Comment: Yes. So you'll likely want to use a split function that returns what was matched.

Comment: Don't know what language we're talking about, but in Python you can get the delimiters returned by using parens in the regex: `m=re.split(r'(\{.*?\}|and)',s)`

Comment: Even in that case it will match the brackets too instead of only what's inside.

Comment: True. Are you saying you think that's a problem?